# How do I write a collection of arrays to csv file in python?

Tags: python, counter, export-to-csv

I have a Counter collection in python that looks like

```
C = [
  ('a', [10, 15]),
  ('b', [20, 23]),
  ('c', [11, 55])
  ...
]
```

I want to write this collection into a csv delimited file that looks like

```
letter    property1    property2
a         10           15
b         20           23
c         11           55
```

I have looked around in stack overflow, most people are trying to only output a dictionary to csv one row at a time. This probably doesn't apply to me. What should I do with my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new list of lists that concatenates the second element of your lists to a list containing the first element of your list. Then you can just use the [`csv.writer` and `writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) methods to write those lists to the file.

```
import csv
D = [ [x[0]] + x[1] for x in C ]
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(D)
```

The line `D = [ [x[0]] + x[1] for x in C ]` can use some explaining.

`[x[0]]` puts the first element of the element of `C` into its own list and then `+ x[1]` takes the second element of your list and adds it to the end of the list we just created. So for the first element in your example `('a', [10, 15])`: `[x[0]]` is the list containing the string `'a'` or `['a']`. `x[1]` is the list `[10, 15]`. The `+` operator concatenates lists. So if we concatenate `['a'] + [10, 15]` we get `['a', 10, 15]` which will write to the csv as you asked for.

Comment: What does `[x[0]] + x[1]` do?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I understand the code now. Just one thing for future reader of this thread: I used `D = [ [x] + C[x] for x in C ]` instead of the one given by the answer because my `C` is actually a Counter collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
c = [
  ('a', [10, 15]),
  ('b', [20, 23]),
  ('c', [11, 55])
]

regex = r"\('(\w)', \[(\d+), (\d+)\]\)"
for x in re.findall(regex ,str(c)):
    print ','.join(x)
```